# Conceptual problems in nuclear physics for students?

Tags: nuclear-physics, education, nuclear-engineering

Is there any good reference for conceptual problems for students which learn nuclear physics first time? I am not searching problems that involve difficult calculations. Quite the converse, they should be computational rather simple but conceptually difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the nuclear physics questions in the Physics GRE test. These are multiple choice questions that are supposed to be answered in a few minutes each. At this link:  http://grephysics.net/ans/type/Advanced%20Topics
You will find a few nuclear physics questions such as these ones from the 8677 test:

http://grephysics.net/ans/8677/85
http://grephysics.net/ans/8677/67